# In PHP why is 24 % 1 equal to 1, shouldn't it be equal to 0?

Tags: php, modulo

I have a conditional statement to check if a number is odd or even in PHP

```
<?php



$stdin = fopen("php://stdin", "r");

fscanf($stdin, "%d\n", $N);

fclose($stdin);


function weird_or_not($N) {

    //check that n is between 1 and 100
    if ($N >= 1 && $N <= 100) {

        //check if n is even
        if ($N % 2 == 0) {

            // check if n is in the inclusive range 2 - 5
            if ($N >= 2 && $N <= 5) {
                echo 'Not Weird';
            }

            // check if n is in the inclusive range 6 - 20
            elseif ($N >= 6 && $N <= 20) {
                echo 'Weird';
            }

            // check if n is greater than 20
            elseif ($N > 20) {
                echo 'Not Weird';
            }
        }

        // otherwise n is odd
        else {
            echo 'Weird';
            echo $N % 2;
        }
    }
}

echo weird_or_not($stdin);


?>
```

When I have an input of an even number it prints out 'Weird', and when I print out $N % 2, for any even number it gives the result as 1 when it should be 0. So why is an even number modulo 2 returning 1 when it should return 0?

Comment: `echo weird_or_not($stdin);` shouldn't  you be calling: `echo weird_or_not($N);`?

Comment: @MattClark vote to close as a typo...

Comment: I checked your code, its working fine with constant value 24,25... What is your exact issue. and what are all the inputs for [`$stdin`]

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was for a hackerrank problem. I guess i didn't fully understand the fscanf function and as @MattClark pointed out it ended up being just a typo $stdin instead of $n